# Extremum of function of two variables

Tags: analysis

How does one show that $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-x^2-2xy-y^2$ has no extremum at $(0,0)$?  I don't know how to show this because the determinant of the Hessian matrix is $0$ at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(0,y) = y^3 - y^2.$ This shows that in any neighborhood of $(0,0),$ $f$ takes on negative values. To show that in any neighborhood of $(0,0),$ $f$ also takes on positive values, we have to be more inventive: How about looking at $f$ along the curve $(x,-x+x^2)?$

Answer (score 0):

A method without using much in the way of theorems is this:

Let $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$.  Then 
$$f(u,v) = 2u^3 - 4u^2 + 3v^2u$$

Now if this has an extremum, say a maximum, at $u=v=0$ then for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently close to $0$ the function $f(\epsilon,v)$ considered as a function of $v$ for fixed $\epsilon$ must have a maximum near $v=0$.  And indeed, if $\epsilon <0$, it will.  But for $\epsilon > 0$ that line will have a minimum, not a maximum.  (Note that the pure $u$ terms can be ignored; for fixed $\epsilon$ they are just a constant.)  So $f(u,v)$ can have neither a maximum nor a minimum at $u=v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Pose $y = -x$. You get $f(x) \equiv 0$. Thus there is a whole line in the $XY$ plane on which your function is equal to $0$, thus $(0,0)$ cant't be an extremal point.

Comment: Doesn't $(x-y)^2$ have a global min. at $(0,0)?)

Comment: Yes but as "extremum" i mean something like a hill, isn't it? This $f$ we are studying has hessian eigenvalues $0 ,  -4$ at 0, so this is something like a parabol repeated on the $y = -x$ plane right?